# Is using Laravel Sanctum to authenticate the users of a SPA will cause an issue when deploying the application backend to multiple AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: laravel, authentication, amazon-ec2, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

> **Laravel Sanctum** is an authentication system for SPAs (single page applications), mobile applications, and simple token-based APIs.

> When authenticating users for SPAs, Sanctum does not use tokens of any kind. Instead, Sanctum uses Laravel's built-in cookie-based session authentication services.

I have an application that consists of a frontend (SPA) and a backend (Laravel API). That backend is deployed to multiple AWS EC2 instances and uses a load balancer to handle distributing the incoming traffic across these EC2 instances.

Now, if I use Laravel Sanctum to authenticate the users of a SPA, isn't that going to cause an issue because I deploy the backend to multiple AWS EC2 instances?

I mean, if the user has been authenticated through the EC2 instance number 1 for example, when he sends another request to the backend, and that request is sent by the load balancer to the EC2 instance number 2 for example, how this instance will know that the user is authenticated already while it is not the one that issued a session for him when he logged-in?